# How to reset the state after a tictactoe game?

Tags: javascript, reset, tic-tac-toe

how do i reset the state of the board after a tictactoe game?

i want to fire the startGame() function where it will clear out all the x's and O's of the board whenever i hit the restart button.

or do you have any other cleaner approach to do so? thank you so much

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')
const XCLASS = "x"
const OCLASS = "o"
const textElementWin = document.getElementById('xowinMessage')
const screenElementWin = document.querySelector('.winningScreen')
const textElementDraw = document.getElementById('drawMessage')
const screenElementDraw = document.querySelector('.drawScreen')
const restartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
const winCombinations=[
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
]

let circleturn

squares.forEach(square => {
        square.addEventListener('click', handleEvent, {once:true})
})


function handleEvent(event){
    const cell = event.target
    const currentPlayer = circleturn ? OCLASS : XCLASS
    placeItem(cell,currentPlayer)
        
    if (checkWin(currentPlayer)){
        screenElementWin.classList.add('show')
        textElementWin.innerText = `${currentPlayer} wins!`

    }else if(checkDraw()){
        screenElementDraw.classList.add('show')
        textElementDraw.innerText = "It's a tie!"
    }
    else{
        swapTurn()
    }
}

restartButtons.forEach(eachbutton => {
    eachbutton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        screenElementWin.classList.remove('show')
        startGame()
    })
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that `element.className` is a space separated list of class names.

1. Assumption: at the beginning of a game, all cells in the grid have the same class name string. This may be the empty string, a single class name, or a space separated list of class names that do **not** include the values of `OCLASS` or `XCLASS`.

   ```
     const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
     const EMPTY_CLASS = squares[0].className; // empty cell class
     ...
   ```
2. Suggestion: don't process clicks on cells that have already been clicked.

   ```
    const cell = event.target;
    if( cell.className != EMPTY_CLASS) {
        return;
    }
    placeItem(cell,currentPlayer)
    ...
   ```
3. Reset the `className` property of all cells to `EMPTY_CLASS` in the `startGame` function. This function can also be responsible for ensuring winning notifications are removed and notifying players of who goes first ('x' or 'o').

   While you could inline the `startGame` code, it may be clearer to separate it from the event handler in the same manner as functions `placeItem` and `swapTurn` have been separated.